# What does this symbol on my hoodie mean?

Tags: translation

[image: Chinese symbol on a hoodie]

Just got this hoodie and was wondering what the symbol meant.

Comment: 爱 is the simplified version, and 愛 is the traditional version. 
  https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=爱

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means Love. It's traditional Chinese.